# Commission on transaction

Tags: arithmetic

A tourist going to UK wants to change some Mauritian rupees into pounds sterling. The bank sells the puond sterling at Rs40.50 to a pound sterling,and charges a commision of Rs75 on the transaction.How many Mauritian rupees does he have to pay to obtain 700 pound sterling?

Answer (score 0):

If the commission is a fixed 75 rupees, the amount of rupees the turist has to pay is 700 pounds worth of rupees plus 75 rupees, which is $40.50 \times 700 + 75 = 28~425$ rupees.